# How do I update a field to use a different field_type?

Tags: entities, 8, configuration

I have created custom field_type for a field in my content type.  The field 'field_content_category' already exists and is an entity_reference. Changing the yml file and importing doesnt work because there is already data for the field.

My custom field_type is an entity reference and a field to type in an integer.

How do I change the field field_type without creating a new field?

Comment: Not sure if this is what the question is about. Can't you change the widget in the ui at /admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]/form-display?

Comment: not quite.  Unless i dont know what Widget means.  At that path i can change some configuration on the widget.  The field is currently an entity_autocomplete on taxonomy terms.  i can change the size and whether it searches by starts with or contains.  it doesnt change the widget itself.

Comment: You are not using the word 'widget' correctly. What you are trying to change is the 'field type'. Check the Field Types API of Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

To change the field type you would have to write an update_hook:

Example:

```
function entity_test_update_8001() {
  // To update the field schema we need to have no field data in the storage,
  // thus we retrieve it, delete it from storage, and write it back to the
  // storage after updating the schema.
  $database = \Drupal::database();

  // Retrieve existing field data.
  $user_ids = $database->select('entity_test', 'et')
    ->fields('et', ['id', 'user_id'])
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllKeyed();

  // Remove data from the storage.
  $database->update('entity_test')
    ->fields(['user_id' => NULL])
    ->execute();

  // Update definitions and schema.
  $manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $storage_definition = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('user_id', 'entity_test');
  $storage_definition->setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED);
  $manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($storage_definition);

  // Restore entity data in the new schema.
  $insert_query = $database->insert('entity_test__user_id')
    ->fields(['bundle', 'deleted', 'entity_id', 'revision_id', 'langcode', 'delta', 'user_id_target_id']);
  foreach ($user_ids as $id => $user_id) {
    $insert_query->values(['entity_test', 0, $id, $id, 'en', 0, $user_id]);
  }
  $insert_query->execute();
}
```

Comment: so in this example, is entity_test my Content Type and user_id the field i wanna change?

Comment: Also this is just changing Cardinality  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldStorageConfig.php/class/FieldStorageConfig/8.2.x  nothing in here seems to change the field type

Comment: This is example is for the general problem, how to change the field definition if there is data stored in the field.

Comment: Do you know of a way to change the field type?